# How to execute multi factor auth from powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-powershell

I need to execute this PowerShell script from C#. I want to disable MFA for a single user.

I have not installed Azure PowerShell. So to execute below script, what prerequisites are needed?

I am unable to find this .dll in my system:

```
Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement.dll
```

My code:

```
string script = "$auth = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement " +
                "$auth.RelyingParty = '*' " +
                "$auth.State = 'Enforced' " +
                "$auth.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = 'Tuesday, November 28, 2017 10:26:43 AM' " +
                //"$upn ="+txtUserName.Text+" "+jplanet@kellyservices.com
                "$upn =abcd@abcd.com " +
                "Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $auth ";

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();

    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript(scriptText);

    ps.Invoke();

    foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Prerequisites:**

Download and Install the following modules.

First install the [Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals RTW](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=286152) from the Microsoft Download Center.

Then install the [Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell (64-bit version)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236297), and click Run to run the installer package.

2. Open Windows PowerShell
3. Run the following command

   `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

   If the output is anything other than
   "unrestricted", run the following command.

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted –Scope CurrentUser`

   Confirm the change of settings.
4. Connect to MsolService via PowerShell
   Running the command below will bring up a popup would require you to enter your Office 365 Administrator Credentials.

   `$UserCredential = Get-Credential 
   Import-Module MSOnline 
   Connect-MsolService –Credential $UserCredential`

**Enable**

```
$St = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$St.RelyingParty = "*"
$Sta = @($St)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ifarr@contoso.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $Sta
```

**Disable**

```
$Sta = @()

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ifarr@contoso.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $Sta
```